# Can a certificate that's been revoked/reissued still be used for SAML signing?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, saml-2.0, x509

I have an organization certificate that needs to be reissued due to the browser distrust (Chrome/FF) of RapidSSL certificates issued prior to a certain date. Reference: https://knowledge.digicert.com/generalinformation/INFO4627.html.

However, we have an in-house SSO setup (SAML 2.0) using the same certificate for signing with our clients. I'm evaluating whether the revocation and reissuance of the certificate will compromise our SSO setup and the new public key would have to be passed onto our clients. From what I can see it shouldn't since the certificate isn't actually expired. I would see it akin to using a self-signed certificate. Am I going about this correctly?

Comment: If it is revoked and published in the CA CRL, and if applications are using the CRLs and/or OCSP, then they will see the certificate as revoked and will refuse to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAML2 uses the certificate format as a convenient way to convey keys. The trust in the certificate is based on a direct configured relationship with the Idp, not through the public CA Root system.

This is what the SAML2 Metadata has to say about certificates:

> As a concrete example, no implications of including an X.509 certificate by value or reference are to be assumed. Its validity period, extensions, revocation status, and other relevant content may or may not be enforced, at the discretion of the relying party.

While it allows the relying party to do additional checks, it does neither require, nor guarantee that any such checks will pass.

Generally I'd say that continuing to use the certificate should be fine, but you need to verify with your configured relying parties (Service Providers in normal SAML2 terms) that they do not validate the certificate.

Comment: This definitely makes sense and was just what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: However the SAML V2.0 Metadata Interoperability Profile (http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-metadata-iop.html) has to say in section 2.6.1


> Subsequent to accepting a metadata instance, a consumer MUST NOT apply additional criteria of any kind on the acceptance, or validity, of the keys found within it or their use at runtime. Specifically, consumers SHALL NOT apply any online or offline techniques including, but not limited to, X.509 path validation or revocation lists, OCSP responders, etc.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr Yes, and that's a good advice. The interop profile is an addon that puts further restrictions to avoid the confusion caused by all different variants the main SAML2 spec allows. But the interop profile is not mandatory - so don't trust that a peer follows it, unless they explicitly states so.